# What happens to Leah after Act III? 

Tags: diablo-iii

At the end of Act III, Leah becomes

> the new human host for Diablo (and all of his brothers).

What happened to her soul? Is she gone forever, like her father Aidan before her? Does the process of becoming the human host of a demon completely consumes your soul or is there still a possibility to save her?

Comment: What a nice title for everyone not yet in Act III, perhaps change it to What happens to Leah after Act III?

Comment: Still spoilerish... Modified it anyway, sorry about that, but couldn't come out with a better title.

Comment: I'm quite sure her father was Diablo itself.

Comment: @StupidOne It was Diablo as the Dark Wanderer, a.k.a. Aidan. We could argue how much humanity was left in him at that moment, but still the human body was that of Leoric's son.

Comment: I spoilerized the important part.  The rest of the question might be a minor spoiler too, but there should be enough foreshadowing through Act II and Act III.

Comment: i think blizzard will tell this in the addons :)

Comment: @MBraedley Also if you look at the conversation achievements, it's clear that Leah's dialogues stop at the Act III

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the end of the Leah's Journey video from the Behind the Scenes DVD, Chris Metzen hints that Leah might return in the next expansion.

> "Her spirit's still out there somewhere. There's a good girl there, that deserves to be saved and brought back from the abyss. So while we don't have any clue yet what subsequent chapters will be, *(a couple of clues)*, I would bet that we would chase that down, because it feels right from a story level and it feels right from a character level."

Comment: Great news :) I felt bad for that poor girl...

Comment: It seems likely they'll bring her back, because the fans want her back. The previous host characters were not loved enough by the fans (probably most folks don't even know their names). Blizzard has been willing to completely retcon the story for lesser things.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think she's dead. Even Covetous Shen hints that she might not be lost forever, when talking about "Leah's Soul" (Act 4, The Light of Hope quest).

Answer (score 3):

When Imperius burned Leah and Diablo came out of the shell, I would assume her body was burned away. As she was innocent and unwilling, her soul should continue on, seeing as this soulstone wasn't implanted in her head. Not drawing from lore, but with Adria escaping, there has to be more to the story.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely she's dead.

In the first game, Diablo's host was Albrecht, Aidan's brother, and he's pretty much dead when you see him in the ending.